# Loading data from .csv file to hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have created a hive table and want to load csv data into it. The data has multiple newline characters in the cell, so it returns an unwanted result.

How to handle multiple newline in hive table?

I have tried this kind of code:

[This format is used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DldSO.png)

[This is whole one row data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjLaw.png)

[this is the result I get from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWUYK.png)

But expected result was only date.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE db_raw.schoolData
(
     Date string, 
     height string,
     weight string,
     ready_to_make string
)

ROW FORMAT serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with serdeproperties (
    "separatorChar" = ",",
    "quoteChar"     = "\""

)     
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 'bucket path'
tblproperties('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

getting this type of data as an output from

```
Select Date from schoolData
```

Output:

```
May 15, 2018                                       |
|  '21232514346020300                                |
|  '21232514346020300 '21232514346020300,OD212325143460203000,62029200,
```

Expected result:

```
May 15, 2018
```

[Referred to this link also but it didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39832280/how-to-load-multi-line-column-data-in-hive-table-columns-having-new-line-charac?rq=1)

same kind of problem

Comment: It helps if you provide an excerpt of your data and the unwanted and wanted result, demonstrating the problem. Also mention what you already tried.

Comment: now i have mentioned it

Comment: Why are you using `"separatorChar" = ","`? It looks like you have two vertical bars, not commas between columns